# Bridge Network in Windows 10 Generates ERR_SSL_BAD_RECORD_MAC_ALERT in Chrome

Tags: networking, windows-10, ssl-certificate, hyper-v

I have a weird problem, for which I researched a lot, but no luck!

I have created an External Switch in Hyper-V, which in turn creates a network bridge on my Wifi adapter. I'm facing this issue that, for a specific Website, when I try to go to the login page, I see the `ERR_SSL_BAD_RECORD_MAC_ALERT` error in Chrome.

I have attached a screenshot: the Website is also there, in case it helps:

[image]

It's worth noting that if I right-click on my Wifi adapter and select `Remove from Bridge`, I don't get this error (of course after a required restart so that my connection works)

I have also included a screenshot of my network adapters and the `Properties` page of the network bridge; maybe that would help:

[image]

Any help is really appreciated.

Thank you

Comment: I have the same super painful problem but I think you're on the wrong site. Try https://superuser.com/

Comment: Thank you @SimonMourier, I was speculating whether I should put my question here; thank you for the suggestion. I'll try there